# SideNav - MaterializeCss - Bind event sidenav close

Tags: javascript, materialize

I can't find any way to bind fire stuff when sidenav is closed

(http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html)

And i can't even find some doc about that.

Actually i'm doing a dirty

```
  $('.drag-target').click(function(){ Stuff });
```

Anyone got a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: There is a open ticket on github and a pending pull request for this feature : https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/pull/3394

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information [here - materialize](https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html)

But I solve my problem with this:

```
$('.sidenav').sidenav().close();
```

Answer (score -1):

In materialize you can just add class `sidenav-close` to close side nav.

```
<a class="sidenav-close"...
```

or

```
<li class="sidenav-close"...
```